# How to get all circles that a Point is contained in?

Tags: mongodb, geojson

Is there a way to find out what polygons (specifically circles) a specific Point lies in?

In this case I would have stored a documents containing circles, like below, I would pass in a latitude and longitude for a point, and would like to get back all documents where the point is within the given circle.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53e3e85ce4b0c2e8227a1dad"),
  "name" : "Menlo College",
  "location" : [-122.1928, 37.45632],
  "radius" : NumberLong(215),
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53e43d19e4b0aeabcb3d3f9d"),
  "name" : "West Valley College",
  "location" : [-122.01021194458008, 37.263226547586207],
  "radius" : NumberLong(604),
}
```

If this is not possible, then is it at least possible with other GeoJSON shapes? Everything I've found so far indicates that the inverse is possible (find all points which like inside a circle), but nothing for this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using MongoDB's `$geoIntersects` Geospatial query operator.

So, if you have a collection of GeoJson polygons and you want to find out all the polygons that intersect with your given point, then you need to run the following:

```
db.places.find( { <locationFieldOfYourDocuments> :
                  { $geoIntersects :
                    { $geometry :
                      { type : "Point" ,
                        coordinates: [long, lat]
                } } } } )
```

In the command above, `loc` is that attribute of each document that contains the coordinates for GeoJson polygon. Also, make sure that you have `2dsphere` index over `<locationFieldOfYourDocuments>`.

Now, to get your original problem solved I will use a little bit of javascript. There may be better solutions but not in my knowledge.

Let's say all your circles are stored in `Circles` collection. I would query that collection and fetch each circle one by one and then perform an intersect with another collection that would contain a single point which would be the one you wanted to query if it intersects with the circles or not. So let the point be stored in `SinglePoint` collection.

The script would look like...

```
db.Intersections.remove({}); // emptying the output collection
var circleCursor = db.Circles.find();
while (circleCursor.hasNext()) {
    var circle = circleCursor.next();
    var coord = circle.location;
    var radiusInRadians = circle.radius * conversionFactorForRadius;
    var intersect = db.SinglePoint.find({loc :
                                         { $geoWithin :
                                           {$centerSphere : [coord], radiusInRadians}
                                         }});
    if (intersect.hasNext()) {db.Intersections.add(circle)} // this will add all intersecting circles to Intersections collection
}
```

All you have to do is save this script in a file (myScript.js) and make a call:

```
mongo DBName pathTomyScript.js
```

This will store all the circles that intersect with your input point in the Intersects collection. All the above collections should be in DBName database.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Although I guess I want to try and avoid having to fetch all circles, because even though there's only a few right now this needs to scale to have tens of thousands of circles, and this will be run thousands of times a day for different points... I guess if I know the maximum radius for a circle, I could fetch all circles within a given distance from the Point.

Comment: I know it is not a smart answer. It is the best i could think of now. Wait for a few days. Someone will probably put a better solution or maybe 10gen will add some functionality to MongoDB in newer versions.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I'm going to use a variation of this until I have a better solution for it.

Comment: @displayName.. i think mongo shud provide feature to store hubs(circles) and function to retrieve the same. and also provide options to search, if the point is within the circle..

Comment: @shivadarshan: it will probably start doing that in later versions. SQL Server provides this functionality as of now.

Comment: @displayName.. can you please explain me how to use this functionality in sql

Comment: @shivadarshan: Use STIntersects() in SqlGeography or SqlGeometry data types to do it in a single command. Google it.