# Find Geopoint with radius which are overlapping geopoint

Tags: sql, mongodb, elasticsearch, geolocation, geometry

As you can see below I have

3 GeoPoint A,B,C With Some Radius
1 GeoPoint K,

[image]

I want to find all the GeoPoint with the radius overlapping K Geo

So answer should be B, C.

So how can achieve this?

Currently I am using Mongodb. But any other database is also fine.

Comment: I think you need a 3rd party library, e.g. [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/). You should find similar open source packages for almost every language. A good starting point might be the [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is opinion-based as is the statement "any other db is fine".
But for the record, the way to do it in ES is as follows:

```
PUT circles
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_shape",
        "strategy": "recursive"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT circles/_doc/A
{
  "location": {
    "type": "circle",
    "coordinates": [
      16.34817123413086,
      48.20968893477074
    ],
    "radius": "2km"
  }
}

PUT circles/_doc/B
{
  "location": {
    "type": "circle",
    "coordinates": [
      16.374435424804688,
      48.20122291334052
    ],
    "radius": "3km"
  }
}

PUT circles/_doc/C
{
  "location": {
    "type": "circle",
    "coordinates": [
      16.386451721191406,
      48.21586595914765
    ],
    "radius": "4km"
  }
}

GET circles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "point",
          "coordinates": [
            16.386795043945312,
            48.208773756674425
          ]
        },
        "relation": "intersects"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
[
  {
    "_index":"circles",
    "_type":"_doc",
    "_id":"B",
    "_score":1.0,
    "_source":{

    }
  },
  {
    "_index":"circles",
    "_type":"_doc",
    "_id":"C",
    "_score":1.0,
    "_source":{

    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it in MongoDB?

Comment: Nope. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416354/8160318